# How to prove that generalized Vandermonde matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-analysis

Given $$A = \left( z_i^{\lambda_k}\right)_{i,j = 1,\ldots, n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
z_1^{\lambda_1} & z_1^{\lambda_2} & \cdots & z_1^{\lambda_n} \\
z_2^{\lambda_1} & z_2^{\lambda_2} & \cdots & z_2^{\lambda_n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
z_n^{\lambda_1} & z_n^{\lambda_2} & \cdots & z_n^{\lambda_n} 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
with $z_1 < z_2 < ... < z_n \in \mathcal{R}_+$ and $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < ... \lambda_p \in \mathcal{R}$,  how to show that A is invertible?

I think I probably need to show that the determinant is not zero but I am not sure how.

I do some derivation and get

[image]

Not sure how to continue. Also not sure if this is the right way.

There is a similar question here [Generalized Vandermonde-Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860559/generalized-vandermonde-matrix) but the conditions are different.

Comment: The determinant is nonzero but it's quite complicated: if the $\lambda_i$ are non-negative integers it's given by an ordinary Vandermonde determinant times a Schur polynomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial#Definition_(Jacobi's_bialternant_formula) ).

Comment: I have followed your notation from the picture. Shall I change $\alpha$ to $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We assume $\alpha_j\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_j>0$ for $j=1,2,\ldots, n.$ The proof will go by induction on $n.$ The conclusion is obviously true for $n=2.$ Assume the conclusion is true for $n-1.$  Assume $\det A=0.$ Equvalently the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. Therefore there exist constants $c_1,c_2,\ldots , c_n$ not all equal $0,$ such that
the function
$$c_1x^{\alpha_1}+c_1x^{\alpha_2}+\ldots +c_nx^{\alpha_n}$$ vanishes at the points $x_1<x_2<\ldots < x_n.$ Hence the function
$$f(x)=c_1+c_2x^{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}+\ldots +c_nx^{\alpha_n-\alpha_1}\quad (*)$$ vanishes at $x_1<x_2<\ldots < x_n.$
By the Rolle theorem there exist $u_1<u_2<\ldots <u_{n-1}$ such that the function
$$f'(x)=c_2(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)x^{\alpha_2-\alpha_1-1}+\ldots +c_n(\alpha_n-\alpha_1)x^{\alpha_n-\alpha_1-1}$$ vanishes at  $u_1<u_2<\ldots <u_{n-1}.$
By induction hypothesis we conclude that
$c_j(\alpha_j-\alpha_1)=0$, $2\le j\le n.$ Thus $c_2=\ldots =c_n=0.$ By $(*)$ we get $f(x)=c_1,$ i.e. $c_1=0,$ a contradiction. The induction step is thus completed. $\blacksquare$

**Remark** By the intermediate value property it can be proved that the determinant is positive. Indeed,
the function $$F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)=\det A(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$$ is continuous.
Let $k$ be  a positive integer  such  $\alpha_1<\ldots <\alpha_n <k.$
Then $\alpha_j<k+j.$
Consider the function
$$g(t):=F((1-t)\alpha_1+t(k+1)
,(1-t)\alpha_2+t(k+2),\ldots,(1-t)\alpha_{n}+t(k+n))$$
Then $g(0)=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and $g(1)=F(k+1,k+2,\ldots, k+n)>0.$ As $g(t)$ does not vanish we conclude $g(0)>0.$

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ to ensure continuity and differentiability of $f$ and allow the use of the Rolle theorem. This is why $z_1,\ldots,z_n\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is important.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier I do not give up positivity of the nodes. Just exponents do not need to be positive.

Comment: I know. But the fact that the points $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are positive allows you to define a differentiable function $f$ on a domain that contains all those points in the first place. I just thought that this is important enough to be mentioned.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier It is mentioned in OP. It is important, as otherwise fractional powers are not well defined. I will mention that assumption in the answer.